# What are the NG, CG, and N iconic group of monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, alignment

I've been playing this game for a *long* time but I cannot recall if there has ever been an iconic group of monsters of neutral good (or for that matter chaotic good or true neutral) alignment native to the other planes in the way that other alignments have their iconic creatures (5e names used - they have had other aliases):

\begin{array}{c|c c c}
 & \text{Lawful} & \text{Neutral} & \text{Chaotic} \\ \hline
\text{Good} & \text{Angels} & ? & ? \\
\text{Neutral} & \text{Modrons} & ? & \text{Slaadi} \\
\text{Evil} & \text{Devils} & \text{Yugoloths} & \text{Demons}
\end{array}

Can anyone fill in the blanks?

Comment: Could be a non-duplicate if you made this 5e-specific, but so long as [[tag:dungeons-and-dragons]] is on here and you reference older concepts, 5e-based answers/updates should go in that question. If you want to edit it to make it 5e-specific, we can probably re-open.

Comment: Also note that (as mentioned in the linked question), the LG exemplars prior to 5e are *archons*, not angels. Angels are an unusual case, in some ways “above” the regular good exemplars, and can be any variant of good, not just lawful good. I do not know if 5e has changed this though.

Comment: @KRyan all angels in 5e are LG but they are the servants of any Good aligned deity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on earlier editions, mostly from the Planescape setting, I think:

- Arborea (Chaotic Good) was home to Eladrins, who were different than
  the Eladrin's we see in 4-5.
- Guardinals were the Neutral Good residents of Elysium.
- The True Neutral residents of the Outlands were the Rilmani.

\begin{array}{c|c c c}
 & \text{Lawful} & \text{Neutral} & \text{Chaotic} \\ \hline
\text{Good} & \text{Archons} & {Guardinals} & {Eladrin} \\
\text{Neutral} & \text{Modrons} & {Rilmani} & \text{Slaadi} \\
\text{Evil} & \text{Devils} & \text{Yugoloths} & \text{Demons}
\end{array}

More (general) info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_planar_races